# How can I remove specific duplicates with Tie::File?

Tags: perl

I'm using this code to remove all duplicates, but I have a need to remove only specific duplicates and leave all others untouched.

In my case if the line matches `/^\s+INDEX 00 \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/` then keep each unique first line, but delete duplicates, and keep all lines that don't match the regex.

```
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $fn or die "could not tie file: $!";
my %seen;
@lines = grep(!$seen{$_}++, @lines);
untie @lines;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $fn or die "could not tie file: $!";
my %seen;
@lines = grep(!/^\s+INDEX 00 \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/ || !$seen{$_}++, @lines);
untie @lines;
```

Comment: Yes, I want to filter a certain type of duplicate.
Nice work.
Thanks.

Comment: @Zaid: This does filter the certain types of duplicates that the OP wants. Are you critiquing this version or the version I had up for about the first minute?

Answer (score 1):

```
@lines = ( $array[0],
             grep { not /^\s+INDEX 00 \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/ } @lines[1..$#lines] );
```

#### Explanation

- An array slice is taken to ignore the first element while filtering with `grep`
- `grep` filters through all elements that don't match the regex
- The resultant array is assigned to `@lines`

Comment: unshift returns the new number of elements in the array. This doesn't work at all. And I think you misunderstood the slightly badly worded question.

Comment: @runrig : Thanks for the head-up, I've updated my answer accordingly.